# Can we attach more than one object in entity framework and do savechanges once

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, updates

I am using **Visual Studio 2012** and **Entity Framework 6.0** and I am doing some `CRUD` operation but I have some challenge to face now that.

I am doing multiple entries in one form and want to update or save those details at once so I am doing now like this:

Create object and store values and **Add / Update** by attach one by one and save changes.

But can I do it like attach multiple object of class and do `savechanges` at last i mean after for loop. So is it running to save multiple `savechanges` by attaching multiple objects?

Example:

```
for(int i=0; i < comingrequestdata.Count(); i++)
{
    ObjectExample obj = new ObjectExampole();

    obj.Value1 = comingrequestdata[i].Value1;
    obj.Value2 = comingrequestdata[i].Value2;
    obj.Value3 = comingrequestdata[i].Value3;

    context.ObjectExamples.Attach(obj);
}

context.SaveChanges();
```

Can I do it like this? I am little bit confused please some one help me.

Comment: Yes,you can do that.Any errors ?

Comment: It is not giving me any error and not updating the values as well.

Comment: Try simply adding this line after your attach statement: `context.Entry(obj).State = EntityState.Modified;` with a `using System.Data` reference and see if that works. **EDIT** Actually I'll post this as an answer since there is a lot to explain.

Comment: @padhiyar Marking any of the answers as answered would be good.

Comment: @Jacob Thanks for remind me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a new item and updating modified items is not really straightforward as just calling one method. You need to distinguish when you are adding a new item or when you are updating. But yes, you can submit multiple items to be updated or added as new. For example, this method can help you do both adding and updating of an entity:

```
public SomeEntity AddOrUpdate(SomeEntity item)
{
    var original = _context.SomeDbSet.Local.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == item.Id) 
                   ?? _context.SomeDbSet.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == item.Id);

    if (original != null) // Updating
    {
        var entry = _context.Entry(original);
        entry.CurrentValues.SetValues(item);
    }
    else
    {
         // New item
         item = _context.SomeDbSet.Add(item);
    }

    return item;
}
```

After a number of calls to this method, call `SaveChanges` on your `DbContext`-based object.

Answer (score 1):

You can try it as shown below.

**.Attach**

> if you have an entity which it already exists in the database, and you
>   have constructed the entity manually, use `.Attach`.

**.AddObject**

> If you have a brand new object, use `.AddObject`.

```
for(int i=0; i < comingrequestdata.Count(); i++)
{
    ObjectExample obj = new ObjectExampole();

    obj.Value1 = comingrequestdata[i].Value1;
    obj.Value2 = comingrequestdata[i].Value2;
    obj.Value3 = comingrequestdata[i].Value3;

    context.ObjectExamples.AddObject(obj);
}

context.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is if you want to add all rows as new rows:

```
for(int i=0; i < comingrequestdata.Count(); i++)
{
    //ObjectExample obj = new ObjectExampole();
    context.ObjectExamples.Add( new ObjectExample {
        Value1 = comingrequestdata[i].Value1,
        Value2 = comingrequestdata[i].Value2,
        Value3 = comingrequestdata[i].Value3
    }

}
context.SaveChanges();
```

This is if you want to modify the existing values in the database (you will need a primary key to identify a record in order to get it from the database, modify it, then save it back):

Or you could use one of your Value1/Value2/Value3 if either of them can uniquely identify the record.

```
for(int i=0; i < comingrequestdata.Count(); i++)
{
    ObjectExample obj = context.ObjectExamples.Where(o => o.ID == Value4); // this is the unique id, assuming it is called ID in the database and Value4 stores its value in your code

    obj.Value1 = comingrequestdata[i].Value1;
    obj.Value2 = comingrequestdata[i].Value2;
    obj.Value3 = comingrequestdata[i].Value3;
    context.ObjectExamples.Attach(obj);
    context.Entry(obj).State = EntityState.Modified;
}
context.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer all of you and I have done somehing like this
Just create the object of the table I mean class like:

```
EntityFrameworkEntities db = new EntityFrameworkEntities();

Classname obj = new Classname();
obj.updatefirstvalue = something;
obj.updatesecondvalue = something;

db.Entry(obj).State = EntityState.Modified;
db.SaveChanges();
```

That's it. and we can also add as more as class we want to update with savechanges at last like:

```
 foreach(var item in collection){
    Classname obj = new Classname();
    obj1.updatefirstvalue = item.something;
    obj1.updatesecondvalue = item.something;

    db.Entry(obj).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
 db.SaveChanges();
```